# read xml file content and replace webpage texts to make a page translator

Tags: xml, jsp

**I am new in xml. I dont know whether the xml structure is right or not.** Now how to read from xml file, i want to display conents condition wise. suppose in my page if there is a word "Man" it should be replaced by 1. and "woman" should be replacd by 2. basically i am making a page translator between two languags. i can not use google translator because project sepecific word meanings should be used.

**xm file**

```
<dic id="Man">
    1
</dic>
<dic id="Woman">
    2
</dic>
```

**jsp page**
suppose in my page there is a text >>>

> Man is not Woman

it should be displayed like >>>>

> 1 is not 2

Comment: You might need to provide more information to get a useful answer (and to avoid this question being closed as unclear). Edit your question to include the chunk of code where you need to handle the data from the XML file, so that people can see clearly what you have done so far and what you are trying to do next.

Comment: i have edited code.. @Bobulous

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: i am not giving any problem. just want to know how to do this. "read xml contents"-- in simple words... i want to make a page which is translated itno a specific language for which i will define meanings in xml file. evrey words corresponding meaning will be defined in xml. after loading a page jsp pages words will be replaced into corresponding words fetched from xml.